# Twitter bootstrap. bootstrap javascript is working but others script wont

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering why my other scripts wont work but the bootstrap.js is working. I have here my code for my functions.php on calling the scripts.

```
<?php
/*Linking of CSS Child Theme to Parent Theme + JavaScript*/
function theme_add_bootstrap()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' ); <!--Working Javascript -->

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-easy-min-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.easy.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-1-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-1.11.0.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap' );
```

The other 3 scripts (custom.js , jquery.easy.min.js, and jquery-1.11.0.js) are working fine in LOCALHOST. however when I uploaded my wordpress site. this scripts are no longer functioning. can someone help with this? by the way this 3 scripts are for PAGE SCROLLING.

Comment: Read about dependencies.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Yeah it might be your javascript include order. Order matters b/c of dependencies. jQuery should be first, then bootstrap, then custom.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you misspelled 'jquery' as 'jqeury'?

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-1-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jqeury-1.11.0.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

But if that *wasn't* misspelled, then maybe you're loading jQuery twice, because `jqeury-1.11.0.js` *looks* like jQuery itself. In that case, get rid of this line. Wordpress has it's own jQuery, which you loaded the first time you put `array('jquery')` as a dependency in a `wp_enqueue_script` statement.

Comment: thank you for the response @yitwail
okay i deleted the jquery-1.11.0.js, however it is still not working.
my custom.js has the pagescrolling effect and the jquery-easy-min.js is its plugin how do SPECIFICALLY  link that? im a bit confused. noob here. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery before bootstrap. Bootstrap depends on it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to place jquery at the top of scripts so it will work fine